# How can I authenticate with K8S API using GKE & kubernetes/client-node?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been trying to authenticate with the K8S API on a cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine, but I'm struggling.

From the GKE API, I have an authentication token for the service account belonging to this project, as well as the certificate belonging to the cluster.

This is what i've got:

```
const config = new KubeConfig();
config.loadFromOptions({
    apiVersion: 'v1',
    contexts: [{ context: {} }],
    clusters: [{ cluster: { 'certificate-authority-data': GKE.masterAuth.clusterCaCertificate, 'server': `https://${GKE.endpoint}` } }],
    users: [{ user: { 'auth-provider': { config: { 'access-token': authToken.credentials.access_token } } } }],
});
const api = config.makeApiClient(CoreV1Api);
```

Now, this exact config worked fine before using https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/ However they're merging with https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript so I thought I'd migrate across.

However now I get an `Error: unable to verify the first certificate` error when attempting to make a request with the API client.

Comment: Is this code running outside the cluster always? if not have you tested the in-cluster authentication?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.